# How to do a Multi field - Phrase search in Lucene?

Tags: java, lucene

Title asks it all... I want to do a multi field - phrase search in Lucene.. How to do it ?

for example : 
I have fields as `String s[] = {"title","author","content"};`
I want to search `harry potter` across all fields.. How do I do it ?

Can someone please provide an example snippet ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Use `MultiFieldQueryParser`, its **a QueryParser which constructs queries to search multiple fields.**.
2. Other way is to use Create a BooleanQuery consisting of TermQurey (in your case phrase query).
3. Third way is to include the content of other fields into your `default` content field.

---

**Add**

Generally speaking, querying on multiple fields isn’t the best practice for user-entered queries. More commonly, all words you want searched are indexed into a contents or keywords field by combining various fields.

---

**Update**

Usage:

```
Query query = MultiFieldQueryParser.parse(Version.LUCENE_30, new String[] {"harry potter","harry potter","harry potter"},   new String[] {"title","author","content"},new SimpleAnalyzer());
IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(...);
Hits hits = searcher.search(query);
```

The `MultiFieldQueryParser` will resolve the query in this way: (See javadoc)

> Parses a query which searches on the
>   fields specified.  If x fields are
>   specified, this effectively
>   constructs:
>
> (field1:query1) (field2:query2)
>   (field3:query3)...(fieldx:queryx)

Hope this helps.

Comment: 3rd option isn't even an option to me, the example I've in the question is dummy... due to the constraints of my app, I require the fields not to be combined...

Comment: 2nd option is what it is... a SECOND option!!!

I am interested in MultiFieldQueryParser, I am doing that, but getting errors in doing it.. I guess that'll be the way to go...

Comment: about ADD, I'll keep that in mind as a good advice.. thank you :)

Comment: @Favonius : do you mind instructing how MultiFieldQueryParser works with phrases ? because parsing with it returns a `Query` object and not the phraseQuery object...

Comment: @Shrinath: Yes it will return the `Query` object. Under the hood it extends the default `QueryParser` and  it parses a query expression using QueryParser’s static parse method for each field as the default field and combines them into a BooleanQuery. The default operator **OR** is used in the simplest parse method when adding the clauses to the `BooleanQuery`. Which again is the **Number 2** option I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

intensified googling revealed this :
http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Phrase-query-on-multiple-fields-td2292312.html.
Since it is latest and best, I'll go with his approach I guess.. Nevertheless, it might help someone who is looking for something like I am...

Comment: This is the second option in Favonius answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `MultiFieldQueryParser` with escaped string. I have tested it with `Lucene 8.8.1` and it's working like magic.

```
String queryStr = "harry potter";
queryStr = "\"" + queryStr.trim() + "\"";
Query query = new MultiFieldQueryParser(new String[]{"title","author","content"}, new StandardAnalyzer()).parse(queryStr);
System.out.println(query);
```

It will print.

```
(title:"harry potter") (author:"harry potter") (content:"harry potter")
```